# Boundary term for Chern-Simons action

Tags: variational-principle, boundary-conditions, quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory, boundary-terms

As discussed in David Tong's lecture series on the edge modes in the quantum Hall effect (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe.html) (page 203), varying the 2+1D Chern-Simons action yields:

$$\delta S=\frac{m}{4\pi}\int{d^3x}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho}[\delta{a_\mu}\partial_\nu{a_\rho}+a_\mu\partial_\nu\delta{a_\rho}]=\frac{m}{4\pi}\int{d^3x}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho}[\delta{a_\mu}f_{\nu\rho}+\partial_\mu(a_\nu\delta{a_\rho})]\tag{1}$$

Which yields the expected $f_{\mu\nu}=0$. We then consider adding a boundary at $y=0$, in which case the second term no longer vanishes. If I understand correctly, we are left with the following boundary term upon integrating the $y$ derivative:

$$\Delta{S}=\frac{m}{4\pi}[a_0\delta{a_x}-a_x\delta{a_0}]_{y=-\infty}^{y=0}$$

Tong states that setting the $\partial_\mu(a_\nu\delta{a_\rho})$ term in $(1)$ to zero can be accomplished by setting $a_t(y=0)=0$ OR $a_x(y=0)=0$, however, I am confused as to why we dont need to set both of them to zero (assuming $\Delta{S}$ is correct). Tong alternatively suggests $(a_t=va_x)_{y=0}$ which makes sense.

Comment: If $a_t \big \vert_{y=0} = 0$ then what will $\delta a_t\big \vert_{y=0}$ be?

Comment: Ok think I misunderstood, if by setting $a_t|_{y=0}=0$ we imply that $a_t|_{y=0}$ is completely fixed (no variations at this point) then yes this makes sense. Thanks.